# Stop Excel Converting "22/50" to 0.44

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel "Application" that on save takes the value from my "Form" worksheet and saves it to my "Data Table" worksheet.

I noticed when the original record value of "Form".Range("I17:K17").Value = "22/50" my save procedure below is showing "0" in the cell for my data table, with 0.44 the actual value showing when clicking the cell and reviewing the function bar. (22 / 50 = 0.44).

Is there a way to prevent Excel from trying to "help" me and save the value exactly as "22/50"? This also goes along with an issue I'm having of Excel cutting off preceding zeroes in some ID fields.

All fields on both forms at this time are to be saved as Text, regardless of type.

Any help appreciated!

```
Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("V1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("I17:K17").value
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. `22/50` stays `22/50` no matter what I try. When exactly is it converted to `0.44` on your sheet?

Comment: @Jean-Francois, your cells must be set as text format by default, which treats entries as they are typed. if the cell formats were set as "general" the fraction would be converted and leading zeroes would be truncated

Comment: @Jean-Francois Corbet, Georges Brisset knows what I was referring to.

Comment: @GeorgesBrisset: No, [they're General](http://i.imgur.com/XfHTvi9.png). Leading zeroes are truncated all right, but `22/50` isn't converted to `0.44` (unless I write `=22/50`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work since all your fields are in Text format:

```
Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("V1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = "'" & Range("I17:K17").value
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have for when a user is adding a NEW record to the data table.

My issue is needing to overwrite a previously added record when user EDITS.

Comment: Adding a `'` character in front of the values forces a text format entry. That is what the part `"'" & Range(etc...` was doing above.

Comment: Marlenunez is right, the apostrophe forces the entry to be preserved as typed. you could also set the format of recipient cells  to "text"

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to the cells not being formatted directly as "Text". Once this was done, everything is saving exactly as typed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cells to automatically change after the user inputs data into them. Set the range(s) of cells that they can edit and use them like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xlEditingRange As Range
    Dim isect As Range

    Set xlEditingRange = Range("a1:a5")
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(xlEditingRange, Target)

    If Not isect Is Nothing Then
        Target.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "'" & Range("I17:K17").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Where Target is the range object that is being changed. See [this MSDN page for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030.aspx)